# Family indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ vs sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, notation, random-variables, nets

Possibly a trivial question, but no harm in asking:

I am reading around and some notes mention a "family of random variables $\{X_n\}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$". Is this the same as the sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$?

The curly brackets and use of the word family seem to indicate that there is no specific order (since in other sections he talks about sequences of random variables), but this seems to not make much sense because in the end the author ends up proving limiting results like the central limit theorem etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Comment: The wording is *really* weird but not inaccurate.  I have to assume that he means a sequence.  I can't think of anything else it could mean and the wording wouldn't be accurate for anything else.... but, dang, that *is* weird wording....

Comment: Well, I would rather write $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ since $0$ is a natural number.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin That depends on who you ask.  There seems to be some regional variation (US mathematicians vs European mathematicians), and I would expect some variation by field (e.g. in computer science, I would imagine that zero-first indexing would lead to zero being thought of as a natural number).  Of course, we are *way* off-topic, now.

Comment: It's fairly common (if sometimes confusing) to see $\{X_n\}$ denoting a sequence.  In any case, the notation itself, $X_n$, indicates that the $X$'s are indexed by $n$, regardless of whether we put them into a set or a sequence.  Implicitly, the notation tells you there is a function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{X_1, X_2, \ldots\}$ that specifies the order.

Answer (score 1):

For me the braces $\{X_n\}$ would suggest that the order is irrelevant (and so we're not taking a limit, say), while brackets $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is much more suggestive that the *order* matters. "Family" normally suggests a set (so no order). Just my 2 cts.